# How to stream (load) an XML file, modify XML Element data, and write to MemoryStream

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have requirements to load large XML files (between 0.5MB - 600MB), decrypt data that is within the XML file, and write that to a MemoryStream.

It's important that the decrypted data doesn't rest on disk.

Below is my current implementation which loads the entire XML document into memory, decrypts the card number and sets the value, and then copies the modified XML document to a `MemoryStream`. However, this implementation isn't feasible as it loads the entire XML document into RAM.

```
public MemoryStream DecryptFile(string xmlFullPath, DateTime encryptionKey)
{
    XNamespace xmlNameSpace = "http://www.xml.com/schema";

    XDocument fileXDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlFullPath);

    IEnumerable<XElement> cardElements =
        fileXDocument
        .Descendants(xmlNameSpace + "card");

    // Iterate over each <card> element within the <batchRequest>.
    foreach (XElement cardElement in cardElements)
    {
        XElement cardNumberElement = cardElement.Element(xmlNameSpace + "number");

        // Read encrypted value
        // Decrypt value

        cardNumberElement.SetValue(decryptedCreditCard);
    }

    // Save the XML document, with the decrypted cards, to a memory stream.
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    fileXDocument.Save(memoryStream, SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);

    // Rewind the stream, so that it's ready to be read from it elsewhere.
    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    return memoryStream;
}
```

I'm pretty familiar with the [`XmlReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.read(v=vs.110).aspx), and I'm using it for other operations.

I've thought about being able to run through the XML document, and simply write out element-by-element to a corresponding MemoryStream, and eventually decrypt the data and write that to the memory stream as the card numbers appear.

However, I am unable to get the raw XML of the start/end element that I'm iterating on. At least, without parsing/loading the entire element, which an operation like ReadOuterXml allows. But I don't want to read the entire element. I simply want to write the raw element-by-element to the MemoryStream, and only handle decrypting the card number's as I come across them.

Note that the card number's are within a serialized object "transaction". i.e. `<transaction>...<number>asdfa3423jasfa</number></transaction>`

So, how can I load (stream) an XML file, modify bits of data in it, and progressively write the content to a MemoryStream?

Comment: You need to use a streaming XML API for this.  Try XmlTextReader.  Also, you are aware that MemoryStream is also all in memory at once, right?

Comment: @hoodaticus yea in regard to the MemoryStream, our testing show's that directly keeping the MemoryStream fully in RAM isn't _as bad_ as loading the entire XML in RAM. The ladder causes out-of-memory exceptions, whereas the MemoryStream is okay _for now_ in our environment and limitations.

Comment: don't forget my XmlTextReader suggestion.  I used it for building fully stream-based services - very fast and small, flat memory usage was a very good thing.

Comment: @hoodaticus that makes sense. I'm going to start going down that route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to read using the `XmlReader` and write all the content using an `XmlWriter`. Remember this is a forward-only cursor, so you have to store whatever you would need as you process it.

Below is a sample function to do something similar to what you need.

```
public static MemoryStream DecryptFile(string xmlFullPath, DateTime encryptionKey) {
    var elemToLook = "number";
    var inElem = false;
    var number = "";
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream))
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFullPath)) {
        while (reader.Read()) {
            switch (reader.NodeType) {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    if (reader.Name == elemToLook)
                        inElem = true;
                    writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    if (inElem) {
                        number = reader.Value;
                        // TODO: This is where your decryption code will go.
                        number = $"decrypted({number})"; 
                        writer.WriteString(number);
                    } else
                        writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                    writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                    writer.WriteComment(reader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                    if (inElem)
                        inElem = false;
                    writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Whitespace:
                    writer.WriteRaw(reader.Value);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    return memoryStream;
}
```

I would suggest you pass in an `Action` delegate to do the processing so you can separate your custom processing with the standard XML processing

Also, if you want to only read the `<number>... </number>` when it is nested inside some other tags like `<transaction>...</transaction>` then you will have to handle that when setting up the `inElem` flag to factor in the nesting.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Modified it slightly for my business needs, but this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

To work with streams of XML rather than entire documents, you can use an `XmlTextReader` for reading the stream and then a corresponding `XmlTextWriter` for putting it into the target `MemoryStream`.

Documentation for these classes can be found here:

XmlTextReader
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader(v=vs.110).aspx

XmlTextWriter
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter(v=vs.110).aspx