# How to return xml file using memorystream and web api

Tags: javascript, c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I have WebApp (using WCF), which backend of app in C# and front side in JS. I need to create webservice which will read data from Oracle database and based on those datas create XML file. Need to save file to MemoryStream and using ajax (js) in front side download this XML file.

If anyone understand what I need to do, please share samples of code or usefull infromation links.
If I coudnt explain well ask me for more details, I can share.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please show some form of effort, describe how/where you are struggling and we will gladly assist.

Comment: It's better for you to decide a direction for yourself because your environment and some of the details are not clear to us, and you need to find a solution that works for you. Take a look at [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42398466/how-to-stream-load-an-xml-file-modify-xml-element-data-and-write-to-memoryst).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On StackOverflow [you should be providing code examples of what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help debug the issue, not write the code for you. That being said, here's a starting point for you:

You can return a `FileContentResult` object from your WebAPI controller that returns an `ActionResult`:

```
return File(byte[] fileContents, string contentType, string? fileDownloadName);
```

To build the XML file, you should be able to parse a simple one out yourself easily enough with a `StringBuilder` or something. If you need something more complicated, look into Microsoft's [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK) NuGet package (though I've only used it to build .xlsx files), and note that you should be able to use a `MemoryStream` when creating a document. From that memory stream you can get the `byte[]` required for the `FileContentResult` return object in your WebAPI endpoint.

As for using an Ajax query to get the download... Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request) for suggestions on how to handle downloading a file via JavaScript and pick your preferred option.

Comment: But why not use a `FileStreamResult` and pass a stream directly? And the `File` function can do the same.

Comment: @Charlieface because I said so, that's why. In all seriousness though, yeah, that'd be better. I just recently converted something over to the method I posted, so that's what I thought of; might have to revisit that now lol.